# Activerecord scope on association value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to add a scope based on an association value.

I have two classes:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :quiz_questions

  scope :entro,     -> { where 'quiz_type = ?', 'base' }
  scope :oltre,     -> { where 'quiz_type = ?', 'oltre' }

end

class QuizQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question

  scope :errors,     -> { where 'correct = ?', false }
  scope :no_errors,     -> { where 'correct = ?', true }
end
```

I use

```
self.quiz_questions.merge(Question.entro)
```

And I have this error.

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "quiz_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ions"  WHERE "quiz_questions"."quiz_id" = $1 AND (quiz_type ...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "quiz_questions".* FROM "quiz_questions"  WHERE "quiz_questions"."quiz_id" = $1 AND (quiz_type = 'base')
```

I just need from a collection of quiz questions to count how many question `{ where 'quiz_type = ?', 'base' }` there are in my collection.

**Update**

QuizQuestion is the join table between a Quiz class and Question Class. I simplify the classes.

By the way quiz_questions collection is something like this:

```
#<QuizQuestion id: 12436, quiz_id: 315, question_id: 253, created_at: "2014-11-07 13:06:18", updated_at: "2014-11-07 13:11:10", solution: 1575, correct: true>,
 #<QuizQuestion id: 12437, quiz_id: 315, question_id: 538, created_at: "2014-11-07 13:06:18", updated_at: "2014-11-07 13:11:10", solution: 2429, correct: true>,
 #<QuizQuestion id: 12441, quiz_id: 315, question_id: 395, created_at: "2014-11-07 13:06:18", updated_at: "2014-11-07 13:11:10", solution: 1999, correct: true>,
```

I use a field in the join table to flag if the user has answered right to a question.

`quiz_questions.errors.count` give me the total errors. I need now to group the total errors by type, and the quiz_type field is in the associated question model.

Comment: So `quiz_type` column is in `quiz_questions` table, right?

Comment: No, quiz_type is in the associated model question

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your scopes to use the hash style, that will make sure that the columns are converted to `"questions"."quiz_type"` instead of using `quiz_type`. It may fix it, you might have to joins instead of merge if that doesn't fix it

```
scope :entro,     -> { where quiz_type: 'base' }
scope :oltre,     -> { where quiz_type: 'oltre' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
quiz_questions.joins(:question).merge(Question.entro)
```